# "Mail delivery deferred" in php registration form on success

Tags: php, database

I've a very weird problem. Please take time to read.
I'm a college student where we have access to net till 1:00am(After that `LAN` gets automatically off).

So, I coded a `php` registration script. On successful registration, a mail was sent to the user on his/her email id. (The form worked correctly). I had to make some changes and at the precise instant  when I click "Register" button on the form (the file was hosted to the server), it struck `1:00`. I didn't use a valid id. (It was `xyz@box.com`)

Now 6 hours later I found that, I've got `462` `Mail delivery deferred` emails in the administrator inbox and the domain was suspended.

Here is my piece of code that will run on successful registration after updating the database:(`send_mail` is a function previously defined)

```
send_mail('Administrator, Tryst IIT Delhi <admin@tryst-iitd.com>',$_POST['email'],'Tryst 2013 - Welcome!','Hi '.$u_name.', \n Thank you for registering for Tryst 2013. \n\nYour Tryst ID is : '.$u_id.'\nLogin using your email id: '.$_POST['email'].'\nLogin using your password : '.$password.'\n\nSee you at IIT Delhi from 1st - 4th March.\n\nRegards,\nTryst 2013 Team');
            $_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']='We sent you an email with your new password! Login using your password and register for events.</a>';//gets printed on the webpage
```

I guess, the reason was that when I clicked "Register",  `send_mail()` got executed, but as my internet was unavailable, the same command kept running and running.
Am I correct? What can be the various reasons of this absurdness?

P.S:Please edit the `question title`. I couldn't guess a better one.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `$_POST['email']` directly. Allowing spammers to use your form and email whomever they please. Bots commonly crawl pages looking for forms they can submit with an email address in the hopes then can hijack your mail server. Most registration forms require a captcha for this reason.

Comment: I did this prior to that:
`$_POST['email'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);`

Comment: I just copied the form and edited a bit to my convenience. I'm just an amateur.

Comment: Can you provide me some useful links?